# Deleting value in hiddenfield when checkbox is unchecked jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am pretty new with jquery and javascript. But i have made this function. When a checkbox is checked, it's value get set in a hiddenfield. Here is the function.

```
<script>
    $('#checkDk').on('change', function () {
        $('#MainContent_hiddenTargetDk').val($(this).val());
        console.log($("#MainContent_hiddenTargetDk").val());
    });
</script>
```

I dont know if this is the best way of doing it, but it works. The problem is when the checkbox is unchecked the value does not get deleted from the hiddenfield. I have been searching a bit around and found this.

```
var value = this.checked ? this.value : "";
```

Can you somehow use this to check if it is checked or not? And if yes how do i incorporate it in my function? 
Here is the checkbox html.

```
<input id="checkDk" type="checkbox" value="208" onselect="getvalue()" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Just set the value you found as the value of the input...

Comment: If you only change the hidden input's value to empty string, you'll still get in as part of the form fields. In case you want to actually remove it from the form if the checkbox is unckecked, see my answer below :-)

Comment: @RonenCypis oh i see mabye that is good enough to do. Then i am sure that no null value get's in. :)

Comment: @KevinJensen when setting the hidden input's value to "", you will have to check for it on your server, because "" is a valid string input. in your case, it seems like empty string ("") is just a way to say "nothing was checked here", and it is always better practice to just exclude irrelevant fields instead of posting them with empty values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script>
    $('#checkDk').on('change', function () {
       $('#MainContent_hiddenTargetDk').val( $(this).prop("checked") ? $(this).val(): "");
        console.log($("#MainContent_hiddenTargetDk").val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just use this.checked, no need to convert it to a jQuery element to read the property.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#checkDk').on('change', function () {
    if(this.checked){
      var hidden = $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
                                 .addClass('chooseNameHere')
                                 .val($(this).val());
      $('#yourFormId').append(hidden);
    }else{
      $('#yourFormId').find('input[name=chooseNameHere]').remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#your_checkbox").prop("checked")` should return `true` or `false` indicating if the checkbox is checked or not.

Try that instead of `val()`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script>
$('#checkDk').on('change', function () {
    if (this.checked) { 
      $('#MainContent_hiddenTargetDk').val($(this).val());
      console.log($("#MainContent_hiddenTargetDk").val());
    } else { $('#MainContent_hiddenTargetDk').val(''); }
});
</script>
```